# Ionic Android Parse-Push Plugin

Tags: cordova, parsing, plugins, ionic-framework, push

I've tried to find the correct ionic plugin for **Parse push notifications** for both Android & iOS platforms.

My requirement is: to receive parse push notification (in both android & iOS).

I have tried this parse push plugin:
https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin

In app.js:

```
run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.ParsePushPlugin){
      ParsePushPlugin.subscribe('SampleChannel', function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
  }, function(e) {
    alert('error'+e);
  });

  ParsePushPlugin.getInstallationId(function(id) {
    // note that the javascript client has its own installation id,
    // which is different from the device installation id.
    alert("device installationId: " + id);
  }, function(e) {
    alert('error' +e);
  });

  ParsePushPlugin.getSubscriptions(function(subscriptions) {
    alert(subscriptions);
  }, function(e) {
    alert('error'+e);
  });

  }
```

When I compile my app on my android device, the alerts work!
But in my Parse Collection (collection called 'Installation') nothing new appear. No rows are stored!

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use Parse, its going to dissapear, you can check this on parse.com. Instead, use OneSignal.

Comment: I have already a backend that uses Parse and we want to use the Parse api channel.

Comment: Did you resolve this? For me, putting client key (not javascript key) on config.xml works